# Is there a way to make my code upload faster?

Tags: php, codeigniter, csv, phpmyadmin

As of now I have 13k records in my csv file. When I try to upload my csv using my function, it seems really slower. Is there a way that I can make it upload much more faster? is there any more configuration I need to do? Btw, I'm using CI framkework.

```
if(isset($_POST["Import"])) {

    $filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    if($_FILES["file"]["size"] > 0) {

        $file = fopen($filename, "r");
         while (($emapData = fgetcsv($file, 10000, ",")) !== FALSE) {

                $data = array(                                                                 
                    'id' => '',
                    'name' => $emapData[0],
                    'empid' => $emapData[1],
                    'datetimex' => $emapData[2],
                    'status' => $emapData[3] 
                );

            $insertId = $this->exmodel->insertCSV($data);
         }

        fclose($file);

        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
          alert('File successfully uploaded');
          </script>";

    } else{

        echo 'Your file has no value. Please select a file that has a size greater that 0 KB/MB.';


    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: its depend on your server configuration, if you want more faster then you ned to upgrade it.

Comment: what do you mean I need to upgrade it sir? please explain more sir.. Thank you.

Comment: you need to process record one by one so it will take a time as per you machine, memory space. so if you upgrade your server to higher level than it will give you more speed.

Comment: So you mean it depends on my hardware server?

Comment: yes of course it is.

Comment: Ah i see. Thank you. But other than that, In terms of the code, is there other way to tweak it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194277/discussion-between-devsi-odedra-and-zeus2026).

Comment: Rather than insert one at a time, you can use CodeIgniter's `insert_many()` function to do them in larger batches. Also, you can turn off indexing while doing all the inserts.